# Python - How to open input files by name

Tags: python, file, input, ppm

```
count = 0
path = input("Please enter the directory you want to get the files from. -> ")
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ppm')):
    file_obj = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    list_of_files.append(file_obj)
    count += 1
```

Pretty much what's happening is that this code scans a user given directory, and opens all the .ppm files in that directory. As it opens them one by one, it appends the (class -  '_io.TextIOWrapper') to a list.

How would a person open the files in order, by name?

Ex. image1.ppm, image2.ppm, image3.ppm, image4.ppm are in my directory.

The code reads and opens the files in this order:

image2.ppm

image4.ppm

image1.ppm

image3.ppm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` over `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ppm'))`.

```
count = 0
path = input("Please enter the directory you want to get the files from. -> ")
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ppm'))):
    file_obj = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    list_of_files.append(file_obj)
    count += 1
```